# Product in Catalogue position not working on frontend with Elasticsearch

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

Using Magento 2.4.6, PHP 8.2, Nginx and Elasticsearch 7
Issue is I am unable to sort the products by position. I see that the position is saved on my backend (Store->Catalogue->Products in Catalogue->Position) however it does not reflect on the frontend.

I see nothing in the error log or exception logs
Reindexing has been done. I disabled all cache.

Anyone having suggestions?

Comment: I identified a module called XXXX_LayeredNavigation that is causing the issue. The issue does not appear to be there when I disable to module.